# solution check for approximating derivative using a Taylor expansion.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I'm wondering if there's in a mistake in either my reasoning or the given solution for the problem and was hoping to have someone double check this for me.

The problem states:

> Let  $g(2)=3$ ,  $g'(2)=1$ ,  $g''(2)=−1$, and  $g'''(2)=2$ . Use the
>   second-degree Taylor  polynomial for  $g'$  centered at  $x=2$  to
>   approximate  $g'(1)$ .

The answer states:

> Taylor polynomial of degree 3 for  $g$  centered at
>   $x=2$  is given by:
>
> $3+1(x-2)-\frac{1(x−2)^2}{2!}+\frac{2(x−2)^3}{3!}$
>
> Hence, the second-degree Taylor polynomial for  $g'$  can be found by
>   taking the derivative of the above expression.
>   $1−(x−2)+\frac{(x−2)^2}{2}$
>
> Therefore, $g ′(1)≈1+1+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{5}{2}$

However, I calculated the derivative as

$1−(x−2)+(x−2)^2$, which gives me $g'(1) = 3$. When taking the derivative of the 3rd degree Taylor polynomial, it seems like the coefficient on the last term should cancel with the $3!$ in the denominator, but I might have overlooked something.

Comment: $3!=3\cdot2\cdot1$.  So $3 \times \frac{...}{3!} = \frac{...}{2 \cdot 1}$.

Comment: For the 4th term in the Taylor series, I have $\frac{g'''(2)(x-2)^3}{3!} = \frac{2(x-2)^3}{6}=\frac{(x-2^3)}{3}$ Then I take the derivative to get $\frac{3(x-2)^3}{3}=(x-2)^2$. With this calculation, I still get $g'(1)=3$. If you've calculated $g'(1)\approx \frac{5}{2}$, what happens to $g'''(2)=2$?